# To get Two data table data in particular format in third data table in C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, datatable

I have two stored procedures summary1 and summary 2 
and get the stored procedures data into two different data table dt1 and dt2 in c#

i want to get data in third data table dt3 in particular format 
like

if dt1 table are as --

```
name |   m1 |   m2   |   m3   |
abc  |   12 |   4    |   8    |
dcd  |   1  |   5    |   7    |
```

dt 2 table data are as -

```
name |   m1 |   m2   |   m3   |
abc  |   5  |   5    |   5    |
dcd  |   5  |   5    |   5    |
```

both data table have same number of columns with same column name .

i want result in dt3  in this format

```
name |   m1     |   m2   |   m3   |
abc  |   12/5   |   4/5  |   8/5  |
dcd  |   1/5    |   5/5  |   7/5  |
```

and bind data table dt3 data to a gridview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Linq for this,

```
var dt3 = from p in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   join q in dt2.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<string>("name") equals q.Field<string>("name") into UP
                   from q in UP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new
                   {
                        name = p.Field<string>("name"),
                        m1 = p.Field<string>("m1") + "/" + q.Field<string>("m1"),
                        m2 = p.Field<string>("m2") + "/" + q.Field<string>("m2"),
                        m3 = p.Field<string>("m3") + "/" + q.Field<string>("m3")
                   };
```

Comment: sen Jacob here i don't want to divide values i just want to add '/' sign in two values like "2/3"

Comment: thanks its working for me but one problem is that show only operator sign not divide the value

Comment: Please check my answer, it is like , `m1 = p.Field<int>("m1") + "/" + q.Field<int>("m1")`

Comment: m also try this syntax but problem in type conversion int to string

Comment: You can take m1,m2 and m3 as string itself. I've edited my post. Try like this. `m1 = p.Field<string>("m1") + "/" + q.Field<string>("m1")`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29345/discussion-between-ashok-and-sen-jacob)

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
i get this error because m1 value are default integer type in dt1 and dt2 data tables

Comment: If you don't mind, please share your code for others too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL query to populate datatable dt3.
Replace table1 and table2 with actual table names.

```
SELECT dt1.name,
       CAST(dt1.m1 AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.m1 AS VARCHAR) as m1,
       CAST(dt1.m2 AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.m2 AS VARCHAR) as m2,
       CAST(dt1.m3 AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dt2.m3 AS VARCHAR) as m3
FROM table1 dt1
INNER JOIN table2 dt2
ON t1.name=t2.name
```

You can put this in stored procedure say summary 3 and make datasource of gridview.

```
Grdview.DataSource=returnedDataset.Table[0];
Grdview.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks i will try to implement this .

Comment: i have no any tables only data tables where the data can be get from stored procedures in c#