# Subtract two data tables into one using one row to subtract with

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to work off this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351997/to-get-two-data-table-data-in-particular-format-in-third-data-table-in-c-sharp) where it shows how to merge one data table with another. My issue is that one data table is **one row** of baseline values that must be subtracted from **each row** of raw data and placed in another baseline offset data table. The **baseline data table doesn't have a date column** but the other two do. I realize I used the join function with Date columns (which is wrong), but I'm unfamiliar when the columns are not equal.

The data tables look like the following

**Raw Data**

```
Date     |  A  |  B    
12/29/14 | 5.5 | 5.8    
12/30/14 | 5.4 | 5.6
```

**Baseline**

```
 A  |  B
5.0 | 5.3
```

**Baseline Offset**

```
Date     |  A  |  B    
12/29/14 | 0.5 | 0.5    
12/30/14 | 0.4 | 0.3
```

---

```
try
{
    con.Open();

    System.Data.DataTable dtData = new System.Data.DataTable();
    System.Data.DataTable dtBaseline = new System.Data.DataTable();

    var dtBaseline_Offset = from p in dtData.AsEnumerable() 
                            join q in dtBaseline.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<string>("Date") equals q.Field<string>("Date") into UP
                            from q in UP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                date = p.Field<string>("Date"),
                                MeasA = p.Field<float>("A") - q.Field<float>("A"),
                                MeasB = p.Field<float>("B") - q.Field<float>("B")
                            };

   string stringsql1command = "SELECT * from Baseline_Offset";
   string stringsql2command = "SELECT * from Baseline";

   SQLiteDataAdapter sda1 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(stringsql1command, con);
   SQLiteDataAdapter sda2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(stringsql2command, con);

   System.Data.DataTable dt3 = new System.Data.DataTable();

   sda1.Fill(dt3);

   Baseline_OffsetDataGridView.DataSource = dt3;
```

Comment: You are subtracting rows before you have filled the tables with data ?

Comment: Essentially yes. The Baseline data is subtracted from each row in the Raw Data. That subtraction result is put in table Baseline Offset.